# How to dynamically change text color in a linux terminal using PuTTy?

Tags: c++, terminal, putty

I have a project for one of my CS classes, and my group wants to build a terminal-based notebook program. One of the features we want to have is the ability to change between a "light" and "dark" mode. Is there a way to dynamically change the color preferences of the terminal like this?

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: you probably want to change the colors your program outputs, not the configuration of the terminal

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I didn't think it was possible either

Comment: From Google, PuTTY is a 'terminal emulator'.   I have used many terminal emulators (such as gnome terminal, QTerminal),  All terminal emulators can accept ansi escape sequences.  Before you reject a free, easy to install emulator for your project, you should try a simple test: The following function shows s contents in green text on my Qterm,  " string green(string s = "") { return (ESC + "[32m" + s); }  My ansi code has 16 foreground colors, with a similar number of background colors, and some special items (bold, underline) as well as cursor positioning.  I dislike ncurses, but it can too.

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY responds to the Linux console's color-palette controls.  Those happen to **not** be *ANSI* escape sequences.

There's no relevant documentation for PuTTY other than its source-code, but the Linux [`console_codes`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) manpage has this information:

```
   ESC ]     OSC      (Should be: Operating system command) ESC ] P
                      nrrggbb: set palette, with parameter given in 7
                      hexadecimal digits after the final P :-(.  Here n
                      is the color (0–15), and rrggbb indicates the
                      red/green/blue values (0–255).  ESC ] R: reset
                      palette
```

(Regarding "ANSI", see the [BUGS](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html#BUGS) section).

That is used in the ncurses terminal description [`linux-c-nc`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-linux-c-nc),

```
linux-c-nc|linux console with color-change,
        ccc,
        initc=\E]P%p1%x%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%02x%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/
              %02x%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%02x,
        oc=\E]R, use=linux-basic,
```

which ultimately became the current [`linux`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-linux) terminal description.  You should be able to change the color palette using [`tput`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html), e.g.,

```
tput -T linux initc 0 255 255 255
tput -T linux initc 15 0 0 0
```

to reverse black (0) and white (15).